# Is it possible to use DialogFlow simply to parse text?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible to use DialogFlow to simply parse some text and return the entities within that text?

I'm not interested in a conversation or bot-like behaviour, simply text in and list of entities out.

The entity recognition seems to be better with DialogFlow than Google Natural Language Processing and the ability to train might be useful also.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

I've never considered this... but yeah, it should be possible. You would upload the entities with synonyms. Then, remove the "Default Fallback Intent", and make a new intent, called "catchall". Procedurally generate sentences with examples of every entity being mentioned, alone or in combination (in whatever way you expect to need to extract them). In "Settings", change the "ML Settings" so the "ML Classification Threshold" is 0.

In theory, it should now classify every input as "catchall", and return all the entities it finds...

If you play around with tagging things as `sys.any`, this could be pretty effective...

However, you may want to look into something that is built for this. I have made cool stuff with Aylien's NLP API. [They have entity extraction](https://aylien.com/text-api/entity-extraction/), and the free tier gives you 1,000 hits per day.

EDIT: If you can run some code, instead of relying on SaaS, you could check out [Rasa NLU for Entity Extraction](https://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/entities.html). With a SpaCy backend it would do well on recognizing pre-trained entities, and with a different backend you can use custom entities.

Comment: I'll try out Aylien. The main reason I went down the DialogFlow route was the failure of all the others I looked at to recognise dates. Looks like Aylien will do this. Cheers.